# What are the differences between GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN and GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN in MWS

Tags: amazon-mws

I am a newbie of MWS API. During my learning, I found that GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN and GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN output something similar. However, some of the offers which are in GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN did not appear in GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN. Therefore, I want to know what is the differences between "lowest offer" and "lowest priced offers". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN.html) returns an Offer element with much more information, particularly the IsFBA, IsFeatured, IsBuyBoxWinner, etc.  This one is meant for one ASIN at a time, while [GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN.html) allows you to pass in 20 ASIN's at a time and just basically gives you pricing info.  It really depends on your use case.  Check out the differences in the Response elements and choose.